# SQL Grouped Table Join

Tags: sql, join, sum

I'm struggling to figure out how join two grouped tables and then perform a subtraction operation

I have these tables with following columns

## Table1: purchases

#### Vendor  | Quantity | Price

## Table2: paysup

#### Vendor  | Paid |

## RESULT TABLE

#### Vendor | PurchasedTotal | PaidTotal |(Purchased - Paid)|

## My very incorrect Sql Query

```
 SELECT t.Vendor, SUM(Quantity * Price) as TotalPurch
    FROM purchases t
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT Vendor, SUM(paid) as TotalPaid FROM paysup GROUP BY Vendor) y
    ON t.Vendor = y.Vendor
    GROUP BY t.Vendor
```

Comment: Please use tags to indicate which database you are using, this is important as "sql" does not tell us which dialect to propose as a solution. Different database vendors have differences in their SQL implementations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT COALESCE(a.Vendor, b.Vendor) AS Vendor
     , a.PurchasedTotal
     , b.PaidTotal
     , (COALESCE(a.PurchasedTotal, 0) - COALESCE(b.PaidTotal, 0)) AS "(Purchased - Paid)"
  FROM ( SELECT Vendor, SUM(Quantity * Price) AS PurchasedTotal
           FROM purchases
          GROUP BY Vendor
       ) a
  FULL JOIN ( SELECT Vendor, SUM(Paid) AS PaidTotal
                FROM paysup
               GROUP BY Vendor
       ) b ON b.Vendor = a.Vendor
```

Answer (score 0):

It is typical in these circumstance to have a vendor table which you do not mention

```
  SELECT v.Vendor
     , purch.PurchasedTotal
     , paid.PaidTotal
     , (COALESCE(purch.PurchasedTotal, 0) - COALESCE(paid.PaidTotal, 0)) AS "(Purchased - Paid)"
  FROM Vendors v
  LEFT JOIN ( SELECT Vendor, SUM(Quantity * Price) AS PurchasedTotal
              FROM purchases
              GROUP BY Vendor
             ) purch ON v.Vendor = purch.Vendor
  LEFT JOIN ( SELECT Vendor, SUM(Paid) AS PaidTotal
                FROM paysup
               GROUP BY Vendor
       ) paid ON v.Vendor = paid.Vendor
  ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can improve readability with the common table expressions ([CTE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchical_and_recursive_queries_in_SQL#Common_table_expression)):

```
WITH paid AS ( SELECT Vendor, SUM(Paid) AS PaidTotal
           FROM paysup
           GROUP BY Vendor
   ),
   purch AS ( SELECT Vendor, SUM(Quantity * Price) AS PurchasedTotal
          FROM purchases
          GROUP BY Vendor
   ) 
/* The main query: */
SELECT 
  v.Vendor, 
  purch.PurchasedTotal, 
  paid.PaidTotal, 
  (COALESCE(purch.PurchasedTotal, 0) - COALESCE(paid.PaidTotal, 0)) AS "(Purchased - Paid)"
 FROM Vendors v
  LEFT JOIN purch ON v.Vendor = purch.Vendor
  LEFT JOIN paid ON v.Vendor = paid.Vendor;
```